# How to convert an image byte array byte[ ] in java to QImage in Qt?

Tags: java, arrays, image, qt

We have a java code to convert a jpeg image to byte array as follows:

```
    BufferedImage bufferimage = ImageIO.read(new File(homePath + "/codebase" + imageLocation));
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferimage, "jpg", output );
    byte [] data = output.toByteArray();

    byte[] imgByteArray = convertFileToByteStream(imagePath, "Image");
    map.put("image", imgByteArray);

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(map);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

this is on the server side and then the byte array is put into a json and sent to the client.

The client is written in C++ and Qt.
So now how to extract this byte array from the json and covert to a QImage in the same jpeg format?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure but you can try something like below:


   `QJsonArray jsonArray; //suppose this contains actual data sent from server
    QJsonValue jsonValue = jsonArray.at(0); // assume 0 is correct index
    QByteArray data = jsonValue.toVariant().toByteArray();
    QImage image = QImage::fromData(data);`

Comment: Thank u Sumit, but we also have a limitation to use Qt 4.8.7 version and Json handling is not supported in that.. QJasonValue and QJasonArray are part of Qt 5 version and above :(

Comment: In that case you may want to use some third party json c++ library just to take care of json stuffs, and if your chosen library provides any api to get either byte array or string then from there you can feed that to Qt methods to get your job done, if you google you will find many json c++ libraries